# await for all files to be fetched

Tags: javascript, es6-promise

I'm using only pure JS and HTML. No frameworks.

I'm fetching a few html files to my index.html. After they are all fetched I'd like to continue with the script. I'm tryint to figure out how to resolve this (I guess with Promises) but cannot make it work. How to wait for all of them to finish?

```
const prepareHead = fetch("../static/_includes/_head.html")
            .then(response => {
                return response.text()
            })
            .then(data => {
                document.querySelector("head").innerHTML = data;
                resolve();
            });

    const prepareHeader = fetch("../static/_includes/_header.html")
            .then(response => {
                return response.text()
            })
            .then(data => {
                document.querySelector("header").innerHTML = data;
            });

    const prepareStaticLinks = fetch("../static/_includes/_static_links.html")
            .then(response => {
                return response.text()
            })
            .then(data => {
                document.querySelector("static_links").innerHTML = data;
            });


    const prepareFooter = fetch("../static/_includes/_footer.html")
            .then(response => {
                return response.text()
            })
            .then(data => {
                document.querySelector("footer").innerHTML = data;
            });

    await Promise.all([prepareHead, prepareHeader, prepareFooter, prepareStaticLinks]);
    // next line should be called only after all files are fetched
    console.log("document prepared");
```

but `await Promise` does not work:
`Uncaught SyntaxError: await is only valid in async functions and async generators`

What is the correct way to do this?

Comment: it already says what you need to do, its only valid in `async function() { ... }`

Comment: async/await syntax is only a different way to write Promises. remove your `await`and you should be good.

Comment: Try `Promise.all(...fetches)` See: [Go Make Things
 > Waiting for multiple all API responses to complete > Calling multiple APIs at once](https://gomakethings.com/waiting-for-multiple-all-api-responses-to-complete-with-the-vanilla-js-promise.all-method/#calling-multiple-apis-at-once)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try replacing

```js
await Promise.all([prepareHead, prepareHeader, prepareFooter, prepareStaticLinks]);
console.log("document prepared");
```

with

```js
Promise.all([prepareHead, prepareHeader, prepareFooter, prepareStaticLinks])
  .then(() => {
    console.log("document prepared")
  });
```

Your other option would be to use `await` inside an `async` function, like so

```js
const getData = async () => {
  const prepareHead = fetch("../static/_includes/_head.html")
          .then(response => {
              return response.text()
          })
          .then(data => {
              document.querySelector("head").innerHTML = data;
              resolve();
          });

  const prepareHeader = fetch("../static/_includes/_header.html")
          .then(response => {
              return response.text()
          })
          .then(data => {
              document.querySelector("header").innerHTML = data;
          });

  const prepareStaticLinks = fetch("../static/_includes/_static_links.html")
          .then(response => {
              return response.text()
          })
          .then(data => {
              document.querySelector("static_links").innerHTML = data;
          });


  const prepareFooter = fetch("../static/_includes/_footer.html")
          .then(response => {
              return response.text()
          })
          .then(data => {
              document.querySelector("footer").innerHTML = data;
          });

  await Promise.all([prepareHead, prepareHeader, prepareFooter, prepareStaticLinks]);
  // next line should be called only after all files are fetched
  console.log("document prepared");
};

getData();
```